# On update app broadcast receiver is getting called two times in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am working on app where I'm capturing instal/uninstall event of any app. For this I'm using `BroadcastReceiver`, everything is working fine but I found that whenever any app get updated then this same `BroadcastReceiver` is called two times.

First is uninstall then Install event. I don't want to capture update event of any app. How I can control this.

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverInstallApp" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

ReceiverInstallApp.java

```
private final String packageAdded = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED";
private final String packageInstalled = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL";
private final String packageUninstalled = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    // this will be the name of the package
    pkgName = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;

    switch (intent.getAction().toString()) {

    case packageInstalled:
        setAppStatusInstall(context, pkgName);
        break;
    case packageAdded:
        setAppStatusInstall(context, pkgName);
        break;
    case packageUninstalled:
        setAppStatusUninstall(context, pkgName);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try removing <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" /> as it is deprecated and will trigger at the same time as the PACKAGE_ADDED action

Comment: @VERT9x Yes but will it solve my problem ?, it trigger only one time when app install/remove and my case is for update

Comment: Probably but I don't have a simple way of testing as it is not in any of my code. Try it and see if it works. If it does I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: It also depends on how you implemented this receiver. Are you checking the action in the onReceiveBroadcast method and handling each one differently?

Comment: @VERT9x Yup. I'm checking

Comment: Do you intend to run only on Android version 5+? Last time I checked, you can use Strings in switches since most Android uses Java v1.6 and lower. Strings in switches are only in Java 1.7 which is used in Lollipop.

Comment: Are you only trying to capture the first install of an app?

Comment: Everything is fine but problem is I found that whenever any app get updated then this same BroadcastReceiver is called two times.

First is uninstall then Install event. I don't want to capture update event of any app. How I can control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove this line from the XML since the value is deprecated:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
```

If you only want the first install of a package, then add a check in the onReceive method before calling your setAppStatus functions like this:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING) && extras.getBoolean(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING))
```

Comment: Well done. from the docs:    EXTRA_REPLACING

Added in API level 3
String EXTRA_REPLACING
Used as a boolean extra field in ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intents to indicate that this is a replacement of the package, so this broadcast will immediately be followed by an add broadcast for a different version of the same package.

Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.REPLACING"